Why H.264 compression artefacts after scene change last longer than a GOP
I have two cameras connected to the same H.264 encoder.
The cameras point to completely different scenes.
I get a very blocky, highly compressed-looking, video for several seconds when I switch from one camera to the other. My GOP is 15, which is 0.5 second and I use CBR (fairly low ~10mbps). Cameras are 1080p30. I am using a hardware encoder.
Artefacts are expected as I do not force a keyframe on scene change, but I was expecting the artefacts to only last for the GOP that was ongoing when the switch happened and once the next GOP starts that the video would be perfect.
Why do the artefacts last for several GOPs after the switch?
My expectation is that the rate control algo aims for a given bitrate over one GOP only. Is this assumption incorrect?
How is this kind of 'scene change' normally handled? Would forcing a keyframe on the first frame after the switch be enough to avoid this problem?


Why do the artefacts last for several GOPs after the switch?

Sounds like you need an IDR keyframe.
A possible solution is to confirm, at each change, that your GOP starts with an IDR keyframe.
Typically you look for a starting byte sequence (in hex) 00 00 01 65  or sometimes reported (in decimal) as 0, 0, 1, 101.
If your GOP starts with a 00 00 01 41 or such then you will get artefacts from (decoder) mixing frame data between the old and the new. An IDR cancels the old data. You need that for a clear picture.

Yes, forcing a key frame on scene change should cure the problem. However, that is not the case, reducing the GOP does not reduce the duration of the artefact as expected. Even with a very short GOP (a few frames), low quality remains for a few seconds. I suspect the rate control algo is aiming for an averate bitrate over a few seconds and if too much of the bandwidth has already been consumed, it reduces quality to maintain its target rate. Any idea if this theory is correct?
